# Outlook IOS sync to Outlook Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, ms-office, exchange-activesync

Now that Microsoft's released Outlook for iOS, does anyone know if it will sync calendars, contacts and tasks with Outlook on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean directly, then no. It's primarily intended to use Exchange server to sync those.

Comment: I appreciate the fast reply, even if it is a bummer that MS still is making this so hard.

Comment: Are your contacts, calendars, and tasks all solely in Outlook? You could try Sync Services (in Outlook Preferences) to sync all Outlook contacts etc. to Apple Contacts, Calendars and so on, then use [SyncMate 5](http://mac.eltima.com/sync-mac.html) to sync from the Apple apps to your iOS directly.
Warnings with this are a) Sync Services is deprecated and going away in the next gen Outlook and b) I have not tested this! But I think it's worth a try.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that but I was considering moving to Outlook.  It's just easier to stay with what I've got.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like most mobile clients, [Outlook for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-outlook/id951937596) does not sync with data that is local to your Mac.  Instead, it communicates directly with the server that your mail/calendar/etc data resides on.  It syncs directly with Exchange 2007 or later, Office 365, Outlook.com (including legacy hotmail.com and live.com email addresses), iCloud, Yahoo! Mail, and Gmail.  It doesn't allow you to set up a generic IMAP/CalDAV/CardDAV account in the first release.

The chances of having Outlook for iOS (or any other mobile client) sync with local data instead of cloud data is extremely low.  Most people want to have the same view to their email, calendar, and contacts everywhere, regardless of which device (and whether it has synced lately with its home computer) they are using.